# Proving a set is a closed lattice cone in B(S) space

Tags: lattice-orders, vector-lattices

Let $S$ be an arbitrary set and $B(S)$ denote the space of all real-valued bounded functions on $S$. Then we know $B(S)$ is a lattice with pointwise maximum or minimum as the lattice operations. We equip $B(S)$ with the topology of uniform convergence too. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a closed sublattice of $B(S)$.

Now, define $W=$ {$f \in B(S)\colon f= g+\alpha\mbox{ for some }g \in \mathcal{A}\mbox{ and }\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$}. Then how to prove that it is a closed lattice cone, that is, to prove that $W$ is a convex cone in $B(S)$ and closed under the topology of uniform convergence and lattice operations?

It is easy to prove that $W$ is a convex cone and that it is closed under the topology of uniform convergence. I am stuck at showing that $W$ is closed under lattice operations. Given $x_1, x_2 \in W$, consider $x_1 \wedge x_2 = (y_1 + \alpha_1) \wedge (y_2 + \alpha_2)$, for some $y_1,y_2 \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Then it is easy to see that $x_1 \wedge x_2 \geq  (y_1 \wedge y_2) + (\alpha_1 \wedge \alpha_2)$. Is the reverse inequality possible?

Any help/hint is truly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if this "counter-example" satisfies all your conditions, but if there $s\in S$ such that $$y_1(s)=0,\;y_2(s)=1,$$ and you consider $\alpha_1=1$ and $\alpha_2=0$, then $$(x_1\wedge x_2)(s)=1$$ and $$((y_1\wedge y_2)+(\alpha_1\wedge\alpha_2))(s)=0.$$

Comment: @amrsa Thank you, yes, this kind of example would work to show that the reverse inequality is not true. But, it still leaves me stuck with the question of how to show that W is closed under the lattice operations.